# TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object when sending e-mail with Django-mailer and Djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser, django-mailer

## The problem

I'm trying to send a [Djoser user's activation email](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#send-activation-email) using [django-mailer](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/).

However, I receive the following error:

**TL;DR:**

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

[image: print of code snippet]

[image: debug]

**FULL:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 144, in perform_create
    settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/templated_mail/mail.py", line 78, in send
    super(BaseEmailMessage, self).send(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/backend.py", line 15, in send_messages
    messages = Message.objects.bulk_create([
                                           ^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/backend.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    Message(email=email) for email in email_messages
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 554, in __init__
    _setattr(self, prop, value)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/models.py", line 150, in _set_email
    self.message_data = email_to_db(val)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/models.py", line 94, in email_to_db
    return base64_encode(pickle.dumps(email)).decode('ascii')
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/users/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 144, in perform_create
    settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/templated_mail/mail.py", line 78, in send
    super(BaseEmailMessage, self).send(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/backend.py", line 15, in send_messages
    messages = Message.objects.bulk_create([
                                           ^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/backend.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    Message(email=email) for email in email_messages
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 554, in __init__
    _setattr(self, prop, value)
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/models.py", line 150, in _set_email
    self.message_data = email_to_db(val)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joaoalbuquerque/pyenv/versions/3.11.0/envs/garvy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mailer/models.py", line 94, in email_to_db
    return base64_encode(pickle.dumps(email)).decode('ascii')
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

### Libraries and versions used (Python 3.11):

```
 "djangorestframework==3.14.0",
 "dj-database-url==1.0.0",
 "psycopg2-binary==2.9.5",
 "django-cors-headers==3.13.0",
 "gunicorn==20.1.0",
 "pyjwt==2.6.0",
 "python-dotenv==0.21.0",
 "djoser==2.1.0",
 "djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.8.0",
 "django-mailer==2.1",
```

### What I've already tried:

I found this related issue on Djoser's Github. However resolution support with django-mailer in version 2.1 didn't work around here.

Related issue: https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/609

Comment: Why do you say `"TL;DR"` at the very start?  Is that part of your error message somewhere?  Do you think we won't read the question?

Comment: I didn't understand. I just wanted to get straight to the point more succinctly. Something wrong?

Comment: That makes sense now, but its not what `tl;dr` implies or how it is generally used.  I guess I could read it as "Summary", but that is also confusing, since there isn't a 2nd section or 3rd section, and its not long enough.  In my opinion, you wanted to get straight to the point and you did that very well - just by how you wrote your question: clear and straight to the point.